# Exception returning: unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, session

catch (Exception ex) is returning 
"unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack"
in this code:

```
 cmsql = cnsql.CreateCommand(); 
 cmsql.CommandText = strsql;
 cmsql.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
 reader = cmsql.ExecuteReader();
 if (reader.HasRows) {
 while (reader.Read()) { 
 Session["User_Email"] = reader["User_Email"].ToString().Trim(); 
 Session["User_Birthday"] = reader["User_birthday"].ToString().Trim(); }
 Response.Redirect("Default.aspx"); }
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding another parameter to `Response.Redirect` method. If you use Response.Redirect without second parameter, the exception `ThreadAbortException` occurs.

```
Response.Redirect("Default.aspx",false);
```

[PRB: ThreadAbortException Occurs If You Use Response.End, Response.Redirect, or Server.Transfer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/en-us)

Comment: try adding false but did not work for me